# How to store dynamic test data in array format and use the same in anther test case in Cypress v.13

Tags: javascript, jquery, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

How to store test data in array format which is generated in one test case and retrieve same test data set in the form of arrays to use in anther test cases in cypress v.13 with cucumber framework ?

Let say I am creating 10 items with their prices in my first test case.

```
Store in items array in var items=[] and price array in    var price =[] as global variable
```

And in  second test wants to used these items generated in first test case.

```
 Retrieve same global variable from   var items=[] and used in Second test case

  
Then (`I store items with price in Gvariable`, ()=>{
    cy.log(`I store items with price in Gvariable`)
    var items =[]
    var price=[]
        cy.get(`.itemsName`).each((items)=>{
            items.push(Cypress.$(items).text()) 
            cy.log(Cypress.$(items).text())
            })
          cy.get(`.betslip-tip__team.teamB`).each((teamB)=>{       
            Team_B.push(Cypress.$(teamB).text())
             cy.log(Cypress.$(teamB).text())
          })
          cy.get(`.price`).each((price)=>{
            price.push(Cypress.$(price).text())
            cy.log(Cypress.$(price).text())
          })
```

I tried with lots of options to store array as global Variable and retrieve it but no success. Some of the efforts as below :

```
 1.      cy.log({items}+" ++++++")
 outPut  --->     [object Object]
         

2.        Cypress.env("price" , price)
          const myArray = Cypress.env("price" );
          cy.log(myArray  ); 
output   -->      Array[4]
   

      
3.         Cypress.env('items',{items})
          cy.log( `items in array`+Cypress.env('items'))
output  --> items in array[object Object]


4.        cy.log(`price val in array `+Cypress.env(`price`))
output  --> price val in array undefined
      

5.      cy.log({items})
output --> log{items: [Georgia, Turkey]}
          
       })
```

Please let me how to handle such scenario is cypress 13 with BDD framework

Answer (score 2):

The cucumber framework doesn't change the underlying mechanics of the Cypress framework which has test isolation enabled by default in v13 see [Test Isolation as a Best Practice](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2023/03/08/test-isolation-as-a-best-practice/)

So you could turn that off, or if that's too risky save the data to disk

```js
Then (`I store items with price in Gvariable`, ()=>{
    cy.log(`I store items with price in Gvariable`)
    var items =[]
    var price=[]
        cy.get(`.itemsName`).each((items)=>{
            items.push(Cypress.$(items).text()) 
            cy.log(Cypress.$(items).text())
            })
          cy.get(`.betslip-tip__team.teamB`).each((teamB)=>{       
            Team_B.push(Cypress.$(teamB).text())
             cy.log(Cypress.$(teamB).text())
          })
          cy.get(`.price`).each((price)=>{
            price.push(Cypress.$(price).text())
            cy.log(Cypress.$(price).text())
          })
  cy.then(() => {
    cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/price.json', { price })
  })
```

or load in Gleb Bahmutov's [data session](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-data-session) to take the headache out of file manipulation

```js
Then (`I store items with price in Gvariable`, ()=>{
    cy.log(`I store items with price in Gvariable`)
    var items =[]
    var price=[]
        cy.get(`.itemsName`)...

  cy.then(() => {
    cy.dataSession('prices, () => price)
  })
```

---

**Cypress.env()** should work between tests in the same spec, but are cleared between specs.

You might just be caught be the closure problem, i.e you have to wait for `prices` to be updated before saving

```js
Then (`I store items with price in Gvariable`, ()=>{
    cy.log(`I store items with price in Gvariable`)
    var items =[]
    var price=[]
        cy.get(`.itemsName`)...

  cy.then(() => {                // deferring saving price until after code runs
    Cypress.env('price'  price)
  })
```